# Docker-compose: Setting a build sequence

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For a php application I have the following *docker-compose.yml*:

```yml
version:'2'
services:
  service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: "service"

  service_debug:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_debug
    image: "service_debug"
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
```

Also in my Dockerfile I have the following context

```dockerfile
FROM php:7.0-fpm-alpine
MAINTAINER Monkey D. Luffy

EXPOSE 9000

VOLUME /var/www/html

#Do build stuff
#....
```

I also have an another dockerfile where I base it on the docker image I build with the dockerfile above where I install the xdebug. This file is named (according to `docker-compose.yml`) `Dockerfile_debug`. This image will contain some debuging tools (eg in my case xdebug but it can be any tool or setting):

```dockerfile
FROM service
MAINTAINER Kurosaki Ichigo

EXPOSE 9001
EXPOSE 9000

RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_autostart=true' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_mode=req' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 ' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_port=9001' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_enable=1' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

So my question is when I run `docker-compose build` how to set the build sequence between 2 services and how to make the image I build from `service_debug` to get based on the latest image from `service`.

In otherwords I want to produce the production ready image and a debug image at the same time in order to be able to test if my application will work in my production-ready docker image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with docker links?
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links